# Hide progress bar in video background

Tags: html, wordpress, video, background

I've created a Wordpress website with a video background on top of the homepage: https://beachvolleylovers.be/

When I go to the website with my iPhone, the video doesn't work (which is normal) but I still see the progress bar at the bottom. You sometimes see that progress bar on desktop when resizing your screen.

How can I hide that?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want video control in a video background? Can't you just remove `controls` attribute altogether in your `<video>` element? Do you want to remove the control from mobile only or both mobile and desktop?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g1rsasa3

Answer (score 0):

Set the controls attribute to false did the trick.